# Testing IFormFile that saves in the correct folder in ASP.NET 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, iformfile

I want to write unit test for this controller. My goal is to check if the file is saving to the `wwwroot/images` folder and I want to check that by matching the file in folder with the `Guid` generated by `imageNameToSave`.

The issue is - two different `Guid` are generated.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateNewsViewModel model)
{
    var imageNameToSave = Guid.NewGuid() + ".jpg";

    var role = await this.newsService.CreateNewsAsync(model.CreatedOn, model.Title, model.Text, imageNameToSave);

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
       model.Image.CopyTo(ms);
       var uploads = 
       Path.Combine(this.hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images");
       var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, imageNameToSave);
       using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
          {
           await model.Image.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
          }
     }

    return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

This is what I have done so far. My question is how can I get the same `Guid` and also delete the created files after the test?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Call_NewsServiceWithCorrectParams_OnPost()
    {
        // Arrange
        DateTime createdOn = DateTime.Now;
        string title = "Tony Stark dies in Avengers!";
        string text = "Tony had to sacrifice himself for the greater good in the battle with Tanos";
        string imageNameToSave = Guid.NewGuid() + ".jpg";

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var formFile = new FormFile(ms, 0, ms.Length, "name", imageNameToSave);

        var newsServiceMock = new Mock<INewsService>();

        var hostingEnvironmentMock = new Mock<IHostingEnvironment>();

        var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var endIndex = currentDirectory.IndexOf(@"\MovieManagement\");
        var wwwrootFolderPath = "\\MovieManagement\\MovieManagement\\wwwroot";
        var path = Path.Combine(currentDirectory.Substring(0, endIndex) + wwwrootFolderPath);

        hostingEnvironmentMock.SetupGet(x => x.WebRootPath).Returns(path);
        var model = new NewsViewModel()
        {
            CreatedOn = createdOn,
            Title = title,
            Text = text,
            Image = imageNameToSave
        };

        newsServiceMock.Setup(ns => ns.CreateNewsAsync(createdOn, title, text, imageNameToSave)).ReturnsAsync(model);

        var createModel = new CreateNewsViewModel()
        {
            CreatedOn = createdOn,
            Title = title,
            Text = text,
            Image = formFile
        };

        var sut = new NewsManagementController(newsServiceMock.Object, hostingEnvironmentMock.Object);

        // Act
        var result = await sut.Create(createModel);

        // Assert
        newsServiceMock.Verify(x => x.CreateNewsAsync(createdOn, title,
                text, imageNameToSave), Times.Once);
    }
```

Comment: This question is incomplete as it lacks enough details that would allow for the proper context of the situation to be understood, which would then allow for a proper answer if available to be provided. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to better understand the actual problem.

Comment: @Nkosi I hope this question is clearer now. Let me know if it needs more clarification.